# Will renaming a folder that is rsynced to a BTRFS volume and snapshotted there double the space necessary?

Tags: backup, rsync, btrfs

I have a setup where I'm backing up a bunch of folders via rsync to an external server onto a BTRFS volume and regularly snapshotting the volume to be able to access different points in time of my backup easily.

Will renaming one of the folders on my live system result in this folder taking up space twice in my backup, once under the old name and once again under the new one?

rsync is using the --delete flag to synchronize the local and remote directories fully.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you can use a patch in this situation to prevent duplicated content files with different names: detect-renamed.diff 
https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync-patches-3.1.2.tar.gz